# ReactJS Form input initial state undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I have a user form which pulls in data from a prop and populates each input field with its value. When I click to open an empty form (as if I'm adding a new user) I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'language' of undefined`.

**State:**

```
   ...  
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    language: this.props.user.language || '',
    description: this.props.user.description || ''
   }
   handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    console.log(this.state);
   }
   ...
  }
```

Input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Language..." id="language" name="language" value={this.state.language} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

It should show the value field as empty if it can't read the value of the user object. I've tried setting the or value to null but this throws the same error.

Thanks

Comment: You'd have to check if "user" existed before trying to access its properties.

Comment: Add a check to see if that property exists also you can make use of defaultProps if needed.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-set-default-props-on-react-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) for this because if you change the user in the `Parent` component it would change the state in the `Child`  as well because it will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps()`. Also, check if `this.props.user` exists on your constructor.

```
...
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    language: this.props.user && this.props.user.language || '',
    description: this.props.user && this.props.user.description || ''
   }
...
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user) {
        this.setState({
            language: nextProps.user.language,
            description: nextProps.user.description
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check `this.props.user` like this to avoid the error :

```
this.state = {
    language: this.props.user ? this.props.user.language : '',
    description: this.props.user ? this.props.user.description : ''
}
```

This is the inline operation using the ternary operators equivalent to :

```
if (this.props.user) {
    return this.props.user.language;
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        language: '',
        description: ''
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user) {
        this.setState({
            language: this.props.user.language,
            description: this.props.user.description
        })
    }
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash method get to set the field as empty if it cant the user is undefined like so 
`_.get(this.props, 'user.language','')`

but it looks like you are not passing a user as a prop